# i want to remove double quotes from a string without replace function

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, string, return-value

I want to remove Double Quote from string `"Hello"` word.

I have array `var ary = ['a', 'b' , 'c']`  Now when I take value from array it's return into string like if I use `ary[0] = "a"` but I want in value like `a` .

Because I have One JSON file That contains

```
{
   "a":{
       "name" : "Emma"
     },
   "b":{
       "name" : "Harry"
     },
   "c":{
       "name" : "Jonny"
     }
 }
```

I want value from Here using Those array like `ary[0].name = Emma`

NOTE : I used `str.replace(/\"/gi,"");   &&  str.replace(/"/gi,"");`  If any Other Idea How can I get than please Replay ASAP.

Comment: That's not valid JSON: It's missing some quotes.

Comment: It's quite unclear what you're asking. The question is full of inconsistencies, and it seems you're confusing JavaScript syntax for the contents of variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your requirement correctly, you can just use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation) like `obj['a'].name`

```
var obj = {
    a: {
        "name": "Emma"
    },
    b: {
        "name": "Harry"
    },
    c: {
        "name": "Jonny"
    }
};

var ary = ['a', 'b', 'c']

for (var i = 0; i < ary.length; i++) {
    console.log(obj[ary[i]].name)
}
```

Here you pass the property key as a string to the bracket notation and it will return the value